# ASP.NET MVC 2 area namespace assignment

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, namespaces, asp.net-mvc-areas

Suppose the root project has `My.Root.Project` namespace. **I wonder what namespace should be assigned to an area classes?** Possible alternatives:

1. `My.Root.Project.Areas.Area1`
2. `My.Root.Project.Area1`

Esthetically, I prefer second one.
However, since I use a **single-project areas**, all the classes created within `Areas\Area1\...` folder are given *long* namespace `My.Root.Project.Areas.Area1` by default. There is too much stupid work in getting rid of the `Areas` part in every created class by hands.
**How to prevent `Areas` from being included into namespace?**

Comment: @Haacked demonstrates first approach here http://haacked.com/archive/2010/01/12/ambiguous-controller-names.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally like the second one.

I think that you can do one of the following things:

- If this is a stand alone project you can call him whatever name you want.
- If this is a folder in another project, in the properties of the areas folder you can choose: Namespace Provider: False.

Comment: It would be perfect, but I have no **Namespace Provider** property for the folder, only **Folder name**. I'm in VS2008.

Comment: In order to have this property you need to have ReSharper installed.

Comment: Seems like there is no other way to avoid automatic insertion of `Areas` into namespace. Accepting despite of can't use it :)